# Probability that the sum on the sixth roll is not a repetition of previous sums

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics

I'm given this sample question:

> If a pair of fair dice is tossed six times, what is the probability that the sum on the sixth roll is not a repetition of the sum on any previous roll?

I figured I should know how to do it. Maybe simplify the question to 2 rolls or 3 rolls instead of 6. However I cannot solve it.

A very thorough explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a very messy calculation because the sums are not equally probable and because sums can repeat between the first and fifth rolls.  Why are you interested?

Comment: It's a given sample question, I figured I should know how to do it. Maybe simplify the question to 2 rolls or 3 rolls instead of 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be the sum of probabilities for the $6$th roll being each one of $11$ possible outcomes times the probability of not getting that outcome on $5$ other rolls.
The probability of getting a sum of $2$ or $12$ are the same so the calculation below pairs outcomes except for $7$.

$P = 2 * \frac{1}{36} * (\frac{35}{36})^5 + 2 * \frac{2}{36} * (\frac{34}{36})^5 +  2 * \frac{3}{36} * (\frac{33}{36})^5 +  2 * \frac{4}{36} * (\frac{32}{36})^5 + 2*\frac{5}{36} * (\frac{31}{36})^5 + \frac{6}{36} * (\frac{30}{36})^5$